# Filter JSON triple nested

Tags: javascript, json, filter

Currently have a JSON file structure and currently trying to utilise the search query to check 3 levels deep.

**Search fields**: `[dynamic].[dynamic].[dynamic].value.title` and `[dynamic].[dynamic].[dynamic].value.description`.

Everything that is stated dynamic is generated through JS anyways, however trying to figure out the most optimal / performance ready.

**Attempt**: This is my current attempt and my thoughts are that if i can get through the nested dynamic json with 3 layers of loops.

This isnt working at the moment, what would the best way be to search a query: "something" and it goes to `[dynamic].[dynamic].[dynamic].value.title` and `[dynamic].[dynamic].[dynamic].value.description` and returns the title

```
const filteredData = Object.values(components)
    .filter(key => key)
    .map(function(something) {
        return something;
    });
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "a11": {
    "a22": {
      "colours": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "fonts": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      }
    },
    "b22": {
      "logo": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "c22": {
      "unordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "ordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      }
    },
    "d22": {
      "head": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "foot": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "e22": {
      "headings": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "time": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 7
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "b11": {
    "f22": {
      "menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "g22": {
      "product-item": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "h22": {
      "search": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "i22": {
      "sub-menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "c11": {
    "j22": {
      "footer": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "k22": {
      "header": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here.

Comment: Just updated - The current attempt is not working and need some assistance in getting a filter going to 3 layers deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all the dynamic keys and access all the static values of a specific third-level dynamic key like this:

```
function query(param) {
    for (lvl1key of Object.keys(json)) {
      for (lvl2key of Object.keys(json[lvl1key])) {
        for (lvl3key of Object.keys(json[lvl1key][lvl2key])) {
          if(lvl3key === param) {
            let title = json[lvl1key][lvl2key][lvl3key].value.title;
            let description = json[lvl1key][lvl2key][lvl3key].value.description;
            //do something with it
            console.log(title, description);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
const json = {
    "a11": {
      "a22": {
        "colours": {
          "value": {
            "title": "title here",
            "description": "something here",
            "priority": 1
          }
        },
        "fonts": {
          "value": {
            "title": "title here",
            "description": "something here",
            "priority": 3
          }
        }
      },
      "b22": {
        "logo": {
          "value": {
            "title": "title here",
            "description": "something here",
            "priority": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
  
  function query(param) {
    for (lvl1key of Object.keys(json)) {
      for (lvl2key of Object.keys(json[lvl1key])) {
        for (lvl3key of Object.keys(json[lvl1key][lvl2key])) {
          if(lvl3key === param) {
            let title = json[lvl1key][lvl2key][lvl3key].value.title;
            let description = json[lvl1key][lvl2key][lvl3key].value.description;
            //do something with it
            console.log(title, description);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  query('colours');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function to store the lower level "value" property object in an array. Or whatever property you want for that matter.

The following code will keep checking for nested objects until the "value" property is found, or there are no more properties that are objects.

```js
var components = {
  "a11": {
    "a22": {
      "colours": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "fonts": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      }
    },
    "b22": {
      "logo": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "c22": {
      "unordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "ordered": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 3
        }
      }
    },
    "d22": {
      "head": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "foot": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "e22": {
      "headings": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "time": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 7
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "b11": {
    "f22": {
      "menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "g22": {
      "product-item": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "h22": {
      "search": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "i22": {
      "sub-menu": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "c11": {
    "j22": {
      "footer": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "k22": {
      "header": {
        "value": {
          "title": "title here",
          "description": "something here",
          "priority": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var arr = []; // to store "value" objects
function getValues(obj) { // recursive function
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { // loop through properties on current level
     if (key === 'value') { arr.push(obj[key]); } // store property object in array
     else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') { // recursive call if object
       getValues(obj[key]);
     }
  });
}

getValues(components);
console.log(arr);
```